# Which is the best way to initialize a std::map whose value is a std :: vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, dictionary, stl

I have the following:

`std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> container;`

To add new items, I do the following:

```
void add(const std::string& value) {
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    values.push_back(value);
    container.insert(key, values);
}
```

Is there a better way to add the value?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the way you do it?

Comment: map::insert takes a pair, so you need `std::make_pair(key, values)` or the constructor `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >(key, values)`

Comment: You aren't initializing a map here. Do you really want to know about *initialization*?

Comment: You should probably define "better"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `std::map` holds `std::pair`s of key-value. You need to insert one of these pairs:. Second, you don't need to make a temporary vector.

```
container.insert(make_pair(key, std::vector<std::string>(1, value)));
```

You can express the above using brace-enclosed initializers:

```
container.insert({key, {value}});
```

Note that `std::map::insert` only succeeds if there isn't already an element with the same key. If you want to over-write an existing element, use `operator[]`:

```
container[key] = {value};
```

Answer (score 4):

With intializer lists (C++11), you could just do `container.insert({key, { value }});` where `{value}` will build a `std::vector` and `{key, {value}}` will build a `std::pair`.

Comment: Inserting a pair takes a single argument, you need another pair of braces.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same using `std::make_pair(key, {s1, s2, s3});` ?

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci yep, but since the compiler has no way of knowing what's the type of `{s1,s2,s3}` you need to specify it: `std::make_pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>("test", {"a", "b", "c"})`.